# How to delete a row in a Google Sheet based on date

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-dates

I have a Google Sheet I'm using to geocode addresses, which shows where current road closures are located.  In my table, I have a date field "StartDate" and a number field "Duration".  "Duration" equals the number of days the road will remain closed after the "StartDate". I need a way to automatically delete the row when the duration of the closure has elapsed (i.e., StartDate plus Duration = new date when row will be automatically deleted).  Is there an easy way to accomplish this delete? I am not a programmer, so any help would be charitable.

Answer (score 1):

Directly accessing date cells in a spreadsheet from a script is kind of painful. I would add a helper column, for example `C2 =value(A2+B2)` if the columns A and B contain StartDate and Duration. This makes the entry in C an integer. Then a script can delete rows based on this value. Like this

```
function cleanup() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var today = Date.now()/86400000 + 25569;
  for (var i = values.length - 1; i >= 0;  i--) {
    if (values[i][2] - today > 1) {
      sheet.deleteRow(i+1);
    }
  }  
}
```

Explanation: `Date.now()/86400000 + 25569` is conversion from JavaScript timestamp to spreadsheet format.  The loop traverses the sheet from bottom up, so that deletion of rows does not mess with enumeration of remaining rows. The comparison `values[i][2] - today > 1` says "value in column C" is greater than today + 1, where +1 is a cushion meant to account for time zone discrepancies. (I presume you can afford to keep an expired task in the spreadsheet for a few hours.) If the column was E, you'd need `values[i][4]` there: enumeration begins with 0 in JavaScript.

One you have this function there, set a trigger (under Resources) to run it daily, or hourly if you prefer.

Comment: I'm surely going to try this